# Keep precise typing on deep cloning an Object, using an inherited method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having a Structure as follows:

```
export class InteriorElement {
  private x: number;
  public draw(canvas: CanvasRenderingContext2D): void {
    throw Error('Draw Method not implemented yet');
  }
}

export class Seat extends InteriorElement {
  public draw(canvas: CanvasRenderingContext2D): void {
   canvas.drawRect(this.x, 0, 20, 20);
  }
}
```

I can generate a new object using:

```
const seat: Seat = new Seat();
seat.x = 5;
```

I can use the draw method of the seat

```
seat.draw(this.canvasContext);
```

Now, in order to avoid modifying the same seat over and over, I'd like to deepCopy the element. But instead of copy / pasting the method to every child, I'd rather use the InteriorElement class only.
So I'd like to have a function (which you are very well invited to improve) like the following:

```
public deepCopy(): InteriorElement {
  const deepCopy: InteriorElement = new InteriorElement(this.id);
  Object.keys(this).forEach((key: string) => {
    if (typeof (this[key]) === 'object') {
      return this.deepCopyObject(this[key]);
    } else {
      deepCopy[key] = this[key];
    }
  });
  return deepCopy;
}

private deepCopyObject(any: any): object {
  const deepCopy: object = new Object();
  Object.keys(any).forEach((key: string) => {
    if (typeof (any[key]) === 'object') {
      return this.deepCopyObject(any[key]);
    } else {
      deepCopy[key] = any[key];
    }
  });
  return deepCopy;
}
```

I can now use a simple:

```
seat.deepCopy();
```

the Problem however is that this will obviously return an InteriorElement. So doing this:

```
const seat2: Seat = seat.deepCopy();
seat2.draw();
```

will result in a 'Draw Method not implemented yet' error. Even though the const is typed, it'll recieve an InteriorElement, so it's gonna be one from now on....

Is there any way to provide deepCopy with a generic Type? Something like:

```
const seat2: Seat = seat.deepCopy<Seat>();
```

Which would result into:

```
public deepCopy<T>(): T {
  const object: T = new T();
  [...]
}
```

unfortunately it throws the: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here - error.
How can I tell the InteriorElement.deepCopy() which child a copy requests?

Comment: What's `this.id`?  Ideally your code should constitute a [mcve] so someone who wants to answer can drop it into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work instead of dealing with fixing errors unrelated to the issue you're having.  I expect the answer here will involve using [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core issue here is that you want to return implement a clone function on a superclass, that returns whatever subclass instance is being copied.

First of all, you want a return type of `this`, which means the method returns the same type as the instance.

Secondly, you want to call the same constructor as this class. And unless I'm mistaken, typescript doesn't make this easy. The type of `someInstance.constructor` is just `Function`, rather than the class constructor you might expect.  But you can force it in a way that gives fairly robust type safety.

```
class A {
  constructor(public data: string) { }

  deepCopy<
    // This generic argument will be the type of the class object
    // that this is an instance of. It must be a subclass of A.
    T extends typeof A
  >(): this {
    // Get the constructor as the constructor of some subclass of A.
    const constructor = this.constructor as T

    // Create the new instance as the same type as `this`.
    const newInstance = new constructor(this.data) as this

    // return the copy.
    return newInstance
  }
}

class B extends A {}

const b1 = new B('some data here')
const b2: B = b1.deepCopy() // works
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1rAPYDsIBcBOArsDungBQAOBARiAJbDQAmYOYAXNLnnZgOYBKRNAC+SFMwCmkigGF0FAJ4AeCagD066ABUAFnRh9JmST0Zg8fAgFtjOaAHc6IENGqToOXR5yKKH9AAzT280cChodGoAK0liNWhNENYQg2g0sEx07DZMYADAgDpoAEl7awJcNw8wLhpQSBgguEKE7WhJAA8cYyYYX39m2AkAPjIBTi805FQNLQBxSXsvDwwcwmJSaEgQ1axuIhI8SOCIdFs66gaIodbZtH37NYPN44BeVIhC5-xDrZ3tOJ7klZHhJKwfKETA5srhMvltv1QhAwBcBjUYAADKYQTF3WY-aDQko5eEeD7Qh7rP7kHGFFhsIQ7HFA2ZJME4Ah4LIrB5KfGoDlcrLE0l5SQSMRiJDXGAAIQ63V6MHgCGlhOoAEZoBTJDC5WQAORnC4M2reMGGgQyx5uABMnAVHy19OkcgUinGiS0DlIAGsIEggA)

The generic parameter `T extends typeof A` says that in the function `T` will be some constructor that is a subclass of A. We don't really care which one.

Then we can simply force some casts for what typescript can't infer.

---

However, where the type safety of this breaks down is if subclasses ever have different constructor signatures this would probably break since `deepCopy` has no knowledge about how to call them.

Comment: thanks this works perfectly :) With 'breaking down' you mean that different constructor signatures would simply be ignored as the parent constructor is 'forced' here? This should be fine, if a class deviation gets more elaborated, I'd question myself, if an inheritance model would still suit in the first place.